# PowerShell 5.1 Get-Service array of computers and array of service names

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

PowerShell 5.1

I noticed when I use `Get-Service` with multiple computers and multiple service names that if a service name is not in one of the computers the execution fails, even if it exists in other computers listed. I've tried the following:

```
get-service -ComputerName $computers -Name $serviceNames -ErrorAction Continue
```

I'd like to list all services specified in computers specified. Some services may be on some of the computers but not all services exist on all computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of doing it would be to not use `Get-Service` for remoting, use `Invoke-Command` instead. Do note that `Get-Service` in newer versions of PowerShell no longer supports remoting.

```
$service = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers { Get-Service $using:service }
```

If you're limited by your remote hosts not having WinRM enabled / need to use DCOM as your remoting protocol, you could use `Get-WmiObject` with a constructed filter, this way, its not particularly pretty but it shouldn't throw when a service is not found in one of the remote hosts:

```
$service = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
$filter = $service | ForEach-Object { "name='$_'" }
$filter = $filter -join ' OR '
Get-WmiObject win32_service -Filter $filter -ComputerName $computers
```